# Law of total expectation in the Efron-Stein inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I was reading the Efron-Stein inequality (see [for example](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~sridharan/concentration.pdf)). To get the context, define $X_1,...,X_n$, a set of iid random variables and $Z=f(X_1,...,X_n)$.

In one step of the proof one uses that for $j>i$, 
$$
E[Z|X_1,...,X_i] = E[\,E[Z|X_1,...,X_j]\,|\,X_1,...,X_i].
$$
I understand that the equality is true by the Law of Total Expectation. But, why is it relevant that $j>i$? Why that equality doesn't work for $j\leq i$?

Comment: The one thing that you should remember for the law of total expectations is that it always 'keeps the least number of variables' which means that if $j < i$, we have $E[E[Z|X_1, \cdots, X_j] | X_1, \cdots, X_i] = E[Z|X_1, \cdots, X_j]$.

Comment: @SandeepSilwal Thanks! Can you provide a reference for that fact?

Comment: Its just the general case of the law of iterated expectations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

[Tower property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)

If $\mathcal F_1 \subset \mathcal F_2$ so $\mathbb E(\mathbb E(Z\mid \mathcal F_2)\mid \mathcal F_1)=\mathbb E(\mathbb E(Z\mid \mathcal F_1)\mid \mathcal F_2)=\mathbb E(Z|\mathcal F_1).$

Since $j>i$ so $\mathcal F_1=\sigma(X_1,\cdots , X_i)\subset \mathcal F_2=\sigma(X_1,\cdots , X_j).$